# Extending a Non-Moose Class: Not a HASH reference at accessor

Tags: perl, moose

I'm Trying to extend a non-moose class, and when I call an accessor defined by moose for my extended class I'm getting the following error:

```
Not a HASH reference at accessor MyGraph::weight (defined at MyGraph.pm line 8) line 8
```

This is the simplified code:

```
package MyGraph;

use Moose;
use MooseX::NonMoose;

extends 'Graph';

has 'weight' => (
   is => 'ro',
   isa => 'Num',
);

no Moose;
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package main;
my $g = MyGraph->new;
$g->weight();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MooseX::NonMoose doesn't, out of the box, enable you to subclass a non-hashref class, and Graph uses an arrayref for its instances. The docs mention this, and suggest using [MooseX::InsideOut](http://p3rl.org/MooseX%3a%3aInsideOut) to enable compatibility with non-moose classes that have other instance types.

Answer (score 2):

> The reference that the non-Moose class uses as its instance type must match the instance type that Moose is using. Moose's default instance type is a hashref.

`Graph` uses `ARRAYREF` as its instance type. [`MooseX::InsideOut`](http://metacpan.org/module/MooseX%3a%3aInsideOut) is the solution.

```
package MyGraph;

use Moose;
use MooseX::InsideOut;
use MooseX::NonMoose;

extends 'Graph';
```

Answer (score -1):

I've never done this but this looks like it might be what you want. http://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::NonMoose

Comment: He is using MooseX::NonMoose.